# How to write a query to display SUM of the quantity if same product having same price in my inventory?

Tags: mysql, sql

My table looks like

```
Product       Price        Qty
A              100          10
B              200          30
A              100          15
A              150          20
```

Two times Price 100 is repeating for product A in my table. It should add the quantity if price value same for the product. My result should be like as follows

```
Product       Price         Qty
A              100           25
A              150           20
B              200           30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `sum()` function  with group by product and price

```
    select t.product, t.price,sum(t.qty) as Qty from your_table t
    group by t.product,t.price
```

Comment: Working fine Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Just use `group by product, price` with `sum` aggregation as:

```
select product, price, sum(qty)
  from tab
group by product, price
order by product, price;
```

Comment: `order by` here is superfluous, since `group by` will implicitly do that anyway (it also wasn't explicitly requested in the question, so is a tad distracting from the answer)

Comment: @eggyal it's nice to learn that property thanks. `order by` is needed for correct ordering, even if the query has `group by` for `oracle` db as an example, but also I tried just now `mysql` implicitly does this as you mentioned.

Comment: @eggyal no it won't . The manual is quite specific on this point.

Comment: @Strawberry: Ah.  Behaviour changed in 8.0.  Prior to that, it did (and the manual was quite specific on that point too—e.g. "*[By default, MySQL sorts `GROUP BY col1, col2, ...` queries as if you also included `ORDER BY col1, col2, ...` in the query.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)*".

Comment: @eggyal Eh? the note under 5.7 says: `Note
GROUP BY implicitly sorts by default (that is, in the absence of ASC or DESC designators for GROUP BY columns). However, relying on implicit GROUP BY sorting (that is, sorting in the absence of ASC or DESC designators) or explicit sorting for GROUP BY (that is, by using explicit ASC or DESC designators for GROUP BY columns) is deprecated. To produce a given sort order, provide an ORDER BY clause.`

Comment: @eggyal and Strawberry nice to have some more refined knowledge, thank you all.

Comment: In a DBMS there's never a guarantee for an ordered result set without explicit ORDER BY. If it's currently returning the "correct " order and the internal implementation changes in the next release you can't claim *it's a bug* (this happens way too often)

Comment: @dnoeth: With respect, whilst the behaviour was deprecated in 5.7, it was still documented and guaranteed.

Comment: @eggyal: It was only guaranteed for that release and the note Strawperry posted clearly states that you should not rely on it, i.e. can change in a future release. Do you actually use deprecated features well knowing it might change in the next release? Btw, it's deprecated since at at least 2010 = MySQL 5.5 (the oldest version found on the MySQL site).